# Any way to crossfade music?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I would like to be able to create a music crossfade in an adventure map that I'm creating. The idea is to overlap two versions of the same song, one the "chill" version, another the "fight" version, and when a player gets in a fight with enemies, crossfade over to the fight version, as well as being able to nicely fade out music in general.

My original idea was to have 2 invisible armor stands act as the source for each of the tracks, then move the armor stands away/towards the player, slowly fading in/out each track. This actually works pretty well, but when the crossfade is over, I make the armor stand emitting the now faded-in song ride the player, so it just sticks with them. This also works, and when the player is running straight ahead, it sounds correct, but when the player strafes, it does like a sawtooth effect on the panning, and is REALLY distracting sounding. Any other ideas for a way to make this kind of thing work?

I've also tried messing with setting the attenuation_distance very high in the resource pack, but that doesn't change anything, though I suspect that it's because it only affects certain entity types anyways.

I am writing a server plugin, so I can do anything available in bukkit/paper, and am even perfectly fine doing things with ProtocolLib or other version specific hacks, but I am not expecting players to have to download a client side mod for this map.